# c++ new input to file from existing input variables

Tags: c++, file, output

So this question might of been asked, but for the life of me, I can not find anywhere. Maybe I'm not phrasing it correctly. Apologies if so.

So basically, I'm writing to a file a list of taxi numbers and rank ids. When I type it in, it writes to the file correctly, but it repeats the same input, if that makes sense.

Here is my code for it:

```
void transactionlog(int taxi_number, int rank_id)
{
    int count = 0;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("transactionlog.txt");

    while (count < 2)
    {
        myfile << "Joined the rank: ";
        myfile << "\n\tTaxi number: " << taxi_number;
        myfile << "\n\tRank id: " << rank_id;
        count = count + 1;
    }


}

void main()
{
    node* front = NULL;
    node* back = NULL;

    int choice;
    int taxi_number;
    int rank_id;



    do {
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter your taxi number: >";
            cin >> taxi_number;
            cout << "Enter your rank id: >";
            cin >> rank_id;
            cout << "\n";
            joinRank(front, back, taxi_number);
            transactionlog(taxi_number, rank_id);

        break;
```

Then here is the output I'm getting (reformatted in the text document)

Joined the rank: 
    Taxi number: 434
    Rank id: 23

Joined the rank: 
    Taxi number: 434
    Rank id: 23

I want the second entry in the file to have different date based of what I input.

Sorry if this is long winded

Comment: For such localized questions there are rarely duplicates. Think again what your program goes, maybe go step by step through it. You'll find out *why* there are duplicate entries, and then you can figure out how to add different data.

Comment: I think you need to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) here.

Comment: You should traverse the list you should be building in `joinRank` and print its entries. (You seem to believe the second `myfile << "\n\tRank id: " << rank_id` should produce a different result from the first `myfile << "\n\tRank id: " << rank_id`.)

Comment: you are writting the last input twice in the functin. so remove the loop. in fact you have to open the file in alpending mode 'ios::app'

Answer (score 0):

first why you use a loop that iterates twice to write the input to file?

second: this loop writes the same last input twice to the file and clears the previous content as long as you use open the file in write mode without specifying the append mode.

correct the function `transactionlog` to:

```
void transactionlog(int taxi_number, int rank_id)
{

    ofstream myfile("transactionlog.txt", ios::app);

    myfile << "Joined the rank: ";
    myfile << "\n\tTaxi number: " << taxi_number;
    myfile << "\n\tRank id: " << rank_id;

    myfile.close(); // to save the content
}
```

Comment: That was from when i was trying something. And thank you for your help. Much appreciated